# Roll above target number with n six-sided die?

Tags: probability

Couldn't find this on the site, despite the number of die questions.

**If I have n six-sided die, how can I find the probability of rolling above x (some target number) with the total sum?**

Examples for clarification:

> example 1. If I have 3 die, I want to roll equal to or greater than a total sum of 12. What is the probability that I would roll equal to or over it?
>
> example 2. If I have 4 die, I want to roll equal to or greater than a total sum of 5. What is the probability that I would roll equal to or over it?

Just for full disclosure... I am not the most "mathy" person.

Comment: No problem. Did you check the article? Were you able to follow it, or did you get stuck somewhere?

Comment: Yeah... the word "moment"... I'll read up on it before trying to figure out if I really don't understand it

Comment: 4 die and want to hit 3 and over, what it means?

Comment: Sorry, is that better?

Comment: In response to your last question, which had gone unanswered about the $\Pr(S\geq 8)$, you had the calculation right. And since I tend to make rookie mistakes from lack of formal training, here I can prove it to you with a line of code for one million simulations: > `mean(colSums(replicate(10^6, sample(1:6 ,2, replace=T))) > 7)
[1] 0.416771
> 15/36
[1] 0.4166667`

Comment: Incidentally, if you don't need more precision than this approximation to the sixth decimal point, you may want to consider just copying and pasting this line in R, simply changing the $2$ and the $7$ to calculate any value you want. It beat the power series by a long shot, doesn't it?

Comment: The best way to go about this depends on what you want to do with this number, as well as what you’re going to use to compute it. For instance, if you want to compute a table of these probabilities, there’s a straightforward spreadsheet construction for that.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3614/how-to-easily-determine-the-results-distribution-for-multiple-dice for a fairly thorough discussion of this topic. It includes links to online dice statistics programs should you only want the answer and one of the answers has the spreadsheet construction that I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the moment generating function as illustrated nicely in [this online document](http://digitalscholarship.unlv.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1025&context=grrj).

Then PMF of the sum of $n$ six-sided fair die can be retrieved like out of a clothesline from:

$$M_X(t)=\frac{1}{6^n}(e^t+e^{2t}+\cdots+e^{6t})^n\tag 1$$

My attempt at giving an intuition of what MGF are can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/238937/67822). The way to look at it is ignoring the exponential part, and just regarding it as some sort of placeholder that is intended to give us back (taking advantage of the rules of exponents) all the possible combinations of throws that add up to the value you are interested in in a systematic way. The "magic" is that that number ends up conveniently placed in front of the exponent ready to be culled.

So in the case of $2$ fair dice $(k=2)$ the probability of each possible sum is given by the numbers in red, and the sum ($X=x$) by the blue-coded exponents:

\begin{align}\small M_X(t)&=\color{red}{\frac{1}{36}}(e^t+e^{2t}+\cdots+e^{6t})^2\\&\small=\left(\color{red}{\color{red}{\frac{1}{36}}\,}e^{\color{blue}{2}t}  + \color{red}{\frac{2}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{3}t}  + \color{red}{\frac{3}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{4}t} + \color{red}{\frac{4}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{5}t} + \color{red}{\frac{5}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{6}t}+ \color{red}{\frac{6}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{7}t}+ \color{red}{\frac{5}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{8}t}+ \color{red}{\frac{4}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{9}t}+ \color{red}{\frac{3}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{10}t}+ \color{red}{\frac{2}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{11}t}+ \color{red}{\frac{1}{36}}e^{\color{blue}{12}t}\right)\end{align}

You can directly read out that the probability of throwing two fair dice and the result adding up to $6$ is the same as the outcomes adding up to $8$, and in both cases it is $\frac{5}{36}.$

---

Regarding Eq. 1, some details:

1. MGF of a discrete random variable is:

$$M_X(t)= E\left[e^{tX}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p_i \,  e^{tx_i}$$

2. In the case of a *single* die, the mgf is:

$$M_X(t)=\mathbb E\left[e^{tX}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{1}{6} \,  e^{tx_i}=\frac{1}{6}(e^t + e^{2t} + e^{3t}+\cdots+e^{6t})$$

3. The random variable defined on the sum $S$ of $n$ dice will be the multiplication of the mgf for one single die (independent):

$$M_s(t)=\mathbb E\left[e^{t(X_1+\cdots+X_n)}\right]=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[e^{tX_i}]$$

---

PARALLEL SOLUTION WITH PROBABILITY GENERATING FUNCTIONS (PGF):

As in the comment, for a single die roll:

$$G(z) =\mathbb E[z^X] =\sum_{x=1}^6 \frac{1}{6}z^x =\frac{1}{6}(z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5 + z^6) =\frac{1}{6} z \, \frac {1 - z^6}{1-z} $$

And for $n$ dice the PGF will be:

$$G(z)=\frac{1}{6^n}\,z^n\,(1-z^6)^n\,(1-z)^{-n}$$

... and continuing with the comments:

the probability for a given sum (s) will be found in front of $z^s$ once we expand this expression. However, I get stuck here, and find [this resource online](https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/generating-functions-for-dice/), where the pgf is finally expressed as (I'm transcribing what follows to be consistent with the notation so far):

$$G(z)=\frac{1}{6^n}\left(z^n\left[\sum_{s=0}^{n} \binom{n}{s}(-1)^s x^{6s} \right]\color{blue}{\left[\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{-n}{j} (-1)^j x^j\right]} \right)$$

where the negative exponent part is a Taylor series.

The coefficient for each possible sum $s = m$ will be given by:

$$\sum_{6s+j=m+n}\binom{n}{s}\binom{n+j-1}{j}(-1)^s$$

Comment: Using this formula (it is possible i did it wrong) I got 2.97278E+91 for `n=3 die` and `t=12 (my target?)` That seems unlikely to be correct?

Comment: @Jeff $t$ is not the target. In fact you should not put in any value for $t$ at all. What you do, if your target is $12,$ is find the term that looks like $\text{something}\times e^{12t},$ and then the "something" (called the "coefficient") is your probability to roll _exactly_ $12.$ To get the probability of rolling $12$ or more, you have to add up the coefficients of $e^{12t},$ $e^{13t},$ $e^{14t},$ etc.

Comment: @DavidK Wonderful! Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Sorry... e is eulers number, right?

Comment: Yes. But here it doesn't even matter, except for the inner workings of the final result. I was in the process of adding more information, but I would suggest that you listen to the Kahn academy videos on Taylor series. I'm a self-learner, so I have treaded the path...

Comment: OH! okay so if I needed to do the same thing for say... 5 dice... set up the same chart thing... the denominator will be `6^5` or `7776`... The odds of getting a 5 (all ones) is `5/7776` ... as it would be `5/7776 e^(5t)` ?

Comment: ONE last thing... so for your chart above, to roll an 8 or above is `5/36 + 4/36 ... + 1/36`? or `15/36`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50240/discussion-between-jeff-and-antoni-parellada).

Comment: Exactly. This is the concept. Familiarize yourself with MGF, characteristic functions and PGF if you are interested in statistics. It's painful, but it pays off.

Comment: I don’t see any benefit to using a sum of exponentials for this. The ordinary generating function $g[x]=(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)/6={x(1-x^6)\over1-x}$ serves just as well since you’re just trying to compute the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(g[x])^n$. Anyway, the recursion formula in that paper is more to the point for what you’re trying to do.

Comment: @amd I was thinking of posting an attachment to the answer using generating functions. It makes a lot of sense. For Jeff, I have my notes on this [here](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/probability_generating_functions.html).

Comment: I think this answer would be much better if it included some guidance as to how to compute these coefficients. Otherwise, it basically reduces the original problem to another unsolved problem. I.e., using g.f.s, these coefficients are either sums of multinomial coefficients or derivatives of the g.f. evaluated at zero, but how does one go about finding these values without, say, multiplying out each power of the original polynomial?

Comment: @amd Thanks for pushing forward, but I think this is pretty much as far as I can take it, and with some very substantial help from the resources provided.

Comment: There’s an equivalent form for your last sum that’s a bit easier to compute in practice: $$P(X=p)\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (p-n)/s\rfloor}(-1)^k{n\choose k}{p-sk-1\choose n-1}.$$ There’s also a simple summation for the CDF, which is what the OP was specifically interested in: $$P(X\le p)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (p-n)/s\rfloor}(-1)^k{n\choose k}{p-sk\choose n}.$$ Here, $p$ is the target number, $n$ is the number of dice, and $s$ is the die size, $6$ in this case. Note, too that by symmetry $P(X=p)=P(X=ns+1-p)$, which can save some work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's calculate the mean and variance of a single dice throw:  mean = 3.5 (easy), and the variance comes to 35/12 after some calculation.  Hence if you throw n dice, the mean total will be 3.5n and the variance will be 35n/12.  So using the normal distribution as an approximation,

prob{Total >x} = Prob {z > (x - 3.5n)/sqrt(35n/12) }

where z is a standard normal variable.  You can plug in the x and the n, but you will have to consult a normal distribution table to get the answer.

Remember this is an approximation so works best if n is large